# Front camera on an iPhone 4S no longer works

Tags: iphone

The back camera works just fine but the front one does not. When I select it, it just freezes. When I quit the app and select it again it presents just a black screen; no image. I tried closing and resetting the phone but that hasn't helped.

Can anyone help me fix this in some free way?

Comment: Wow. I was surprised to find that [this has been asked and answered here already](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61113/front-facing-camera-stopped-working-on-the-iphone-4s). You won't get a free solution -- at the very least you need a replacement camera and some tools to do the repair. But it's not expensive to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @IanC to find the duplicate, so before we close this here is the answer.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61350/46541

> This is a hardware problem. This comes up when the ribbon connector
>   from the camera to the main circuit board comes loose or gets
>   disconnected altogether. If you have the right tools and enough DIY
>   skills to open up your iPhone, it's a very simple fix that should be
>   fairly obvious to see. Otherwise, the Apple Store should be able to
>   repair it for you (I would think free of charge, but who knows).
>
> If you do want to take apart your iPhone and attempt the repair
>   yourself, [PowerBook Medic](http://www.powerbookmedic.com/iphone/) has some really nice instructions for taking
>   apart all versions of iPhones from 3GS and above. They also sell
>   replacement parts and will repair it for you as well if you want.
>   (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation nor prior experience with this
>   company, so use at your own risk.)